# Why MyISAM is default MYSQL engine?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, storage-engines

Many developers agrees: "In most cases InoDB is better (faster and more reliable) than MyISAM".
So, what is a reason to MYSQL creators set MyISAM as default engine?
Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MyISAM hasn't been the default storage engine for years.

The [default_storage_engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_default_storage_engine) was changed to InnoDB in MySQL 5.5.5, which was [released](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.5/en/news-5-5-5.html) in 2010-07-06.

Comment: Oh, you are right. They changed default engine. Thanx! 
But I wander why WAMP still using MyISAM as default (using configuration file - even today:
WAMP v 3.1.7:
 - MySQL v 5.7.24
 - MariaDB v 10.3.12
).
... but this should be question for WAMP.

Comment: I found a [discussion thread](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,145343,145357) that says WAMP decided to set MyISAM the default because they kept fielding tech support calls from users who were corrupting their InnoDB tables. I would guess that users try to move InnoDB files around manually, not realizing that you can't do that. That's one advantage of MyISAM — each table is self-contained, it doesn't have ties to a central tablespace file for the data dictionary.